# Is there any better data structure to perform a multi-dimensional free text search?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

If we have a list of User objects arrive at your application, for repetitive usage you may cache them in memory by adding it to the ArrayList.

Now, if the search scenario occurs, it may happen on any field like first name, last name, and address for example.

We can solve this problem by indexing these data into Solr. Elastic-like stack and then fetch them through APIs.

Is there any simple way to handle it within Java?

Comment: Do you know about [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/)?

Comment: If you want to do it without framework, the proper approach is by using **inverted indices** (the go-to data-structure for this). And then rank match results for example with BM-25. Since these operations can trivially be converted into matrix operations/linear algebra, you can also let your GPU compute it (hardware acceleration). What you get by doing that is a search engine thats faster and better than what you will find on majority of apps.